# How do I get all cookies in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this php cookie creation:

```
setcookie('reservations', $data, time() + (1800), "/", null, false, false);
```

I have a "reservations" cookie in my chrome browser as expected.

I have this JS instruction:

```
alert(document.cookie);
```

The problem is that this JS instruction produces :

```
PHPSESSID=ma9q30jvq3dcqpnf503i1id1c6
```

It's not my cookie ! So, where is mine ?

Comment: @Davedude — Yes, it is: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: The code works fine when I test it. The cookie you see if the PHP session cookie, so you have (or have had) sessions enabled at some time. That won't interfere with other cookies you set though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I just understood my error, my cookie in the browser was from the time when the "httpOnly" parameter was set to "true" ! It has just been updated.